# IBM Watson Assistant: Entity overlapping issue in conversation

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I am creating a chatbot for students. I am facing a problem in one of my 
use cases. Students need to get the subjects in a particular year (Bot give the 
subjects only semester wise). But the problem is I have two entity @year 
and @semester.

My entity values for @year and @semester is given below. Also I gave some
synonyms for that.
@year values are : 1,2,3
@semester values are :1,2

When the user mention as first year the values of @year:1 and @semester 
is also set as 1, but here actually need to take the input from the user 
for semester.I already done for ask the semester based on @semester in a 
slot, but the value set int @semester is not invoking that.

How can I solve this conflict?

My expected conversation is below

> Student -Get me the list of subjects in first year.
>   Bot - Tell me the course name? `enter code here
>   student - A
>   Bot - Tell me the semester?
>   Student - give semester number
>   Bot - The subjects in first year first semester of A are "Listing  Subjects"

But the output is like this

> Student - Get me the list of subjects in first year.
>   Bot - Tell me the course name?
>   student - A
>   Bot - The subjects in first year first semester of A are Listing Subjects

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to check these [tips for working with slots](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-slots#dialog-slots-tips), including those on [avoiding slot filling confusion](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-slots#dialog-slots-avoid-slot-confusion).

You would need to add conditions or clarifications when capturing the data. Another option is to break up the conversation in two dialog steps. First, get the year and course name, next, in a separate dialog node, capture the semester and look up the actual information to respond.